# I want to change the icon in the sidebar

Tags: wordpress

Using WordPress, I want to find a way to change the icon.

You can see some icons in SideBar such as 'Dashboard', 'Profile' and  'Collapse Menu'.

I will be happy with changing the 'Collapse Menu' Icon.

In menu-header.php, there is description about that button like this.

```
echo '<li id="collapse-menu" class="hide-if-no-js">' .
        '<button type="button" id="collapse-button" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Collapse Main menu' ) . '" aria-expanded="true">' .
        '<span class="collapse-button-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>' .
        '<span class="collapse-button-label">' . __( 'Collapse menu' ) . '</span>' .
        '</button></li>';
```

I think I must change the class called 'collapse-button-icon' in CSS file.
But I don't where it is and how.

I tried with inspect.
So I find this CSS makes the icon.

```
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font: normal 20px/1 dashicons;
    speak: none;
    padding: 4px 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    background-image: none!important;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

font: normal 20px/1 dashicons;
```

With the style above, I can see the icon but without that I can't see any icon.

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list with all the wordpress dashicons.

https://www.kevinleary.net/wordpress-dashicons-list-custom-post-type-icons/

After finding a specific icon, you are able to change it with some css.

```
 .dashicons-NameOfTheIcon::before{
    content: "\f105" !important;
   }
```

Just use admin-collapse for the "Collapse" Icon.

```
.dashicons-admin-collapse::before {
   content: "\f105" !important;
}
```

Dashicons you could use in the css-content:

https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#buddicons-buddypress-logo

Comment: Sounds good. But I want to create my own icon not Wordpress dashicons,

Comment: And how are you going to do that, @EkaterinaAntropova. You should put them in a font, attach that font to this stylesheet and then style it further, cause thats how this system works and can control it easy.

Comment: @Drovalla. Would you send me some examples using font. I can't understand it.

Comment: This source might be helpfull:
https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/wordpress/custom-dashicons.html#.XSXnf6bgrFx

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser developer tools (F12) and inspect that class to see where from CSS is going. Bootstrap files most probably.

You can overwrite that class CSS with yours and change icon look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far I understand that you want to replace admin icons with your own icons.
So follow the instructions...

Register your own icon library in admin head. For example i have been registerd the FontAwesome icons.

```
function my_FAwesome_icons() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_FAwesome_icons');
add_action('wp_head', 'my_FAwesome_icons');
```

Then just register your own style sheet to override the dashicons...

```
function my_admin_styles_register() {
    echo '<link href="/path/my-admin-styles.css"  rel="stylesheet">';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_admin_styles_register');
```

In your my-admin-styles.css file you can try example css like this:

```
icon16.icon-media:before,
#adminmenu .menu-icon-media div.wp-menu-image:before {
    font-family: Fontawesome !important;
    content: '\\f0a4';
}
```

How to find FontAwesome Unicode, check the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder how I can use font-family. I don't know about using SVG exactly.

Comment: content: '\\f0a4'; is Unicode version of icons. you will find all the FontAwesome Unicode version of icons in their website. here you can find the font awesome "address-book" icon unicode https://fontawesome.com/icons/address-book?style=solid